# How can one tell is a message is spoofed from one phone to another but "about" a third party?

Tags: spoofing, sms

This question is about whether the source phone number of an SMS message can be spoofed and, if so, what forensic measures might be taken to determine and prove that that has occurred.

Assume that a friend of mine is being harassed & intimidated by an old romantic interest.  As part of this, my friend suspects that harasser/abuser will falsely claim that my friend has actually been the threatening party.  I have reason to think that as "proof" of this harassment my friend's malevolent ex is trying to create a false record of threatening texts on ex's phone that appear to have originated from my friend's phone number. In fact, however, I believe such texts likely came from someone actively conspiring with the vicious ex who has enough technical knowledge & capability to spoof the sending phone number of a text, at least at a superficial level.

So:  Can the sending phone number of a text as it appears on a recipient's phone be spoofed, such that instead of the real source phone number the specific phone number of a particular, targeted person appears to be the origin? If so, what technical measures can be taken to reveal that the sending number of the message was spoofed?  What evidence does spoofing a phone number--as it appears on a text recipient's phone--leave?

Comment: This is a massive wall of text with few relevant details. Could you edit this down to the technical details of what is going on? We do not need the inter-personal details.

Comment: Depending on locality, you can get a restraining order just by saying you are afraid of someone. This is a legal question. We are unable to answer something with so much conjecture. (PS: I'm sorry for your troubles.)

Comment: @Calmbynature, I'm going to try to massively rework your question so that you might get an answer to the real technical question that I think is at the heart of it: what forensic signs does one have to look for when one suspects the phone number of a received text message has been spoofed.  That *is* the technical, information-security question you are trying to ask, correct?